# i18next - Apply custom formatting

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I have 2 namespaces:

- The first one is global and contains business related glossary
- The second is scoped to a specific page

```js
// global ns
{
  "amendment": "amendment"
}

// page ns
{
  "action": "Enter your $t(global:amendment) below."
}
```

My use case in a react component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{t('amendment')}</h1>
      <p>{t('action')}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

I want to format the text contained in my `h1` element using an uppercase transformation.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

I already think of using context and do the following:

```js
// global ns
{
  "amendment": "amendment",
  "amendment_uppercase": "Amendment"
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{t('amendment', {context: 'uppercase'})}</h1>
      <p>{t('action')}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The issue here is I have to duplicate all my translation keys, and I have a lot of global glossary.

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions, one of them is to define a built in i18next formatter and defining a key that is specific to the page, a `header` needs to be with an upper case.
So, I've defined a `header` key that re-uses the value of amendment from global, but applies a custom formatter (`ucwords`)

```js
i18next.init(
  {
    lng: 'en', // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
    resources: {
      en: {
        global: {
          amendment: 'amendment',
        },
        page: {
          header: '$t(global:amendment, ucwords)',
          action: 'Enter your $t(global:amendment) below.',
        },
      },
    },
    interpolation: {
      format: function (value, format, lng) {
        if (format === 'ucwords') return [value[0].toUpperCase(), value.slice(1)].join('');
        if (value instanceof Date) return moment(value).format(format);
        return value;
      },
    },
  },
  function (err, t) {
    // initialized and ready to go!
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = t('page:header');
    document.getElementById('action').innerHTML = t('page:action');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/i18next@23.2.11/dist/umd/i18next.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header"></h1>
<div id="action"></div>
```